# How to render element in gwt?

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

From last few months I am working on gwt-ext.In that I am using a doLayout() method of Container class.Here is description of it.

*Force this container's layout to be recalculated. A call to this function is required after adding a new component to an already rendered container. If you are not dynamically adding and removing components after render, this function will generally not need to be called.*

Do this method is basically used to render container.
Now I am using core gwt 2.3. Is there any method to render the container in gwt.or any other way to achieve this ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, you are using gwt-ext and not extgwt :(  my mistake....

Comment: I have used gwtext & now I am using gwt2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, GWT does not require this. Just call `.add()` on any `Panel` to add children. They should be immediately visible.